# Передача параметра ASP.NET CORE WEB API

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-webapi

Как передать в get запрос xml строку, например:  ..../k/xmlstr

xmlstr:

```
<root><one>Hello</one></root>
```

Сам контролер:

```
public ActionResult<Object> Get(XmlDocument xml)
```

Comment: Вы собрались в строку запроса засунуть XML? Передавайте его в теле запроса.

Comment: @iluxa1810, да все верно, только не понятно как.

Comment: попробуйте повесить на параметр атрибут  [FromBody]

Comment: уже пробывал, не работает

Comment: и такая же ситуация с json

Comment: Я не уверен, что стандартный маппинг способен создать вам XmlDocument...

Comment: я пробывал XmlDocument заменить на string, результат тотже

Comment: Чистые строки тоже хреново обрабатываются. Вот тут есть решения https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers . Или можно завернуть в отдельный объект с одним полем типа string и туда зафигачить ваш XML.

Comment: я так понял, что когда указываеш xml строку в url сам браузер это не воспренимает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через GET метод не получиться передать. Сам браузер не воспринимает другой формат кроме как QueryString. Только через запросы, где есть Body (например, POST) что xml, что json.

Можно закодировать Json или Xml в query вид, а потом раскодировать на беке:

https://www.urlencoder.org/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.8

Так-же есть ограничение длины Get запроса на чуть больше 2000 символов.

Comment: я сделал через base64, закодировал xml в base64

Comment: @Yaroslav base64 не будет работать, как минимум все "+" пропадут, возможно другие символы тоже

Comment: да я это заметил